# Json call returning the same random value

Tags: html, json, random, image

So I am making a website to display images from a folder with an endless scrolling feature attached to it. I just about got it down, the only problem is that I have a function in javascript that calls a "createImge" function that calls a json from a php file that selects a random image and returns the path of that image. The problem is when I call createImage multiple times in a row it returns the same image and the php doesn't make a new random number to select the file. any ideas on how I can get createImg() to make the php pick a different random number when called multiple times in a row???

index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request json test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var totalLoad;
var loadedImg=new Array();
var maxLoaded=20;
var loadFirst=5;
var bufferLoad=3;
var imgSrc;

function loadTop(){ 
    for(var i=0;i<loadFirst;i++){
    createImg();
    }    
}
function remove(id)
{
    $('.'+id).remove();
}
function createImg(){

    $.getJSON('json-data.php', function(data) {
        alert("Return json-data"+data.img);
        $('#showdata').html($('#showdata').html()+"<div id="+getImageName(data.img)+" ><img width=\"450px\" src=\""+data.img+"\"></div><br/>");
    });

}
function getImageName(src){
var path = src;
var tarr = path.split('/');      // ["static","images","banner","blue.jpg"]
var file = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "blue.jpg"
var data = file.split('.')[0];  // "blue"
return data;

}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        // grab the scroll amount and the window height
        var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
        var documentHeight = $(document).height();

        // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
        var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

        if(scrollPercent > 80) {
                for(var i=0;i<bufferLoad;i++){
                createImg();
            }
        }
        if(totalLoad>maxLoaded){

        }
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="showdata" style="width:450px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<script type="text/javascript">  
loadTop();
</script>  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

json-data.php code:

```
$files = glob("Approved/*.*");
$no = sizeof($files)-1;

$random = rand(0, $no);
$imgHold=$files[$random];

$imgPull = array('img' =>$imgHold);
echo json_encode($imgPull);

?>
```

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Have you tried using mt_rand() instead?

Comment: yes it still returns the same json code when called multiple times in a row

Comment: Possibly you are seeding it too quickly, so every copy gets the same automatic seed (= time).  Try using a counter to explicitly seed each instance: 1, 2, 3, 4,...  Don't use 0 as a seed!